# BibTeX fails to encode cyrillyc when a cyrillyc symbol appears first in author field of a bibtex entry

Tags: bibtex

Here is an example document with a single citation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}

\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    \cite{test}
    
    \clearpage
    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
    \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

The bibtex `test.bib` file contents:

```
@misc{test,
    author = {ВВВ ВВВ ВВВ},
    title = {БББ БББ БББ}
}
```

Is rendered to: [image: img]

What are those blank squares at the beginning of the reference author?

Here is how it is encoded in document.bbl file:

[image]

Bytes:

[image]

But if I put any english character at the beginning of the `author` field:

```
@misc{test,
    author = {tВВВ ВВВ ВВВ},
    title = {БББ БББ БББ}
}
```

Then it is encoded and rendered correctly:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{test}
tВВВ ВВВ~ВВВ, ``БББ БББ БББ.''

\end{thebibliography}
```

[image]

It doesn't happen with `title` field though.
I observe this problem with all the popular latex compilers: `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex`.

Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: bibtex is 8-bit and so doesn't handle utf8, sometimes is works, sometimes it fails and then you have to use commands. Use biblatex + biber if you want full utf8-support.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, biblatex + biber acutally helped, I am extremely grateful to you! You can post the answer if you wish :)